# Argon2 example using BouncyCastle library

Tags: cryptography, passwords, bouncycastle, argon2-ffi

Since version 1.61, the BouncyCastle library supports the Argon2 password based key derivation function. However, I cannot find an example how to use the Argon2 algorithm through the BouncyCastle API. Can someone give a hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at class `org.bouncycastle.crypto.test.Argon2Test` in the source code distro for bouncycastle 1.61

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk. Am I right that there is no "official" API in javax.crypto for a password based key derivation functions, where something like "argon2" can be used als algorithm name? So one has to explicitly use the `org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Argon2Parameters` classes, right?

Answer (score 6):

If you look for an example, you can look into the [Spring Security source code on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/search?q=Argon2&unscoped_q=Argon2), because Spring Security Crypto uses BouncyCastle for Argon2 password hashing.

If you just want to use a library for [Argon2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/argon2/Argon2PasswordEncoder.html) password encryption, you could also use [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) [Crypto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#crypto) (has only [2 optional compile dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/5.2.0.RELEASE)).

```java
Argon2PasswordEncoder argon2PasswordEncoder = new Argon2PasswordEncoder();
String aCryptedPassword = argon2PasswordEncoder.encode("password");
boolean passwordIsValid = argon2PasswordEncoder.matches("password", aCryptedPassword);
```